# Laravel Facades/Mail - Error Code 554 5.5.1 but manual SMTP Mailing works

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I am using Laravel 5.7 and got a problem, when i try to send mails via the following code, i get the error code "554 5.5.1". But this only applies to recipients outside of the mailserver. On the mailserver itself i can send the mails e.g. From test@[myDomain] to no-reply@[myDomain], but not to an gmail address or something else.

Now the really strange thing:

When using a little SMTP-connection script the mail will be send correctly. Internaly and externaly no problems. Also when i use Outlook to connect to the mailserver from my local machine, no problem.

It seems that something is off with my Laravel configuration, but i cannot figure out what. I also refreshed the config cache multiple times.

this is my controller function:

```
// ClientMatching is a Mailable
Mail::to('[externalMail]')->send(new ClientMatching());
```

this is my .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=[myDomain]
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=test@[myDomain]
MAIL_PASSWORD=[myPassword]
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@[myDomain]
```

this is my config/mail.php

```
return [

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', '[myDomain]'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 25),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'test@[myDomain]'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', '[myName]'),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('test@[myDomain]'),

'password' => env('[myPassword'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],
];
```

this is my Mailable

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ClientMatching extends Mailable
{
   use Queueable, SerializesModels;

   public function __construct()
   {
       //
   }

   public function build()
   {
       return $this->view('mails.client-matching');
   }
}
```

Comment: im facing the same issue, manually send same email withmailable works but not notifiable (verify email interface in user model)

Comment: I've made a workaround. I'm using a custom class for sending the mails, but still use the Mailables to render the content for them. Works pretty good and i've got full control over the sending process right now.